# what is declaration error in remix ide and how to solve it

Tags: remix, solidity-0.5.x

[image]What is declaration error here! I can't figure it out and the error is shown as an unidentified declaration error. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Function `createTokens` is declared `external`, but you are calling it inside the contract.

In order to be able to call it from both inside and outside the contract, declare it `public`.